# Rails 4+: where to store custom validation msgs used across models

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have custom validation messages that I use in several different models:

```
# models/user.rb
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: { message: "This is a required question" }
end

# models/pet.rb
class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: { message: "This is a required question" }
end
```

I'm a little familiar with the `en.yml` config, but that specifies messages per model:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        person:
          attributes:
            name:
              blank: "This is a required question"
        pet:
          attributes:
            name:
              blank: "This is a required question"
```

And that just seems very verbose and not developer-friendly.

My solution was to create an initializer file and store my custom validation messages in a hash there:

```
# config/initializers/custom_validation_messages.rb
CUSTOM_VALIDATION_MESSAGES = {
  required: "This is a required question"
}
```

And then to use them as:

```
validates :name, presence: { message: CUSTOM_VALIDATION_MESSAGES[:required] }
```

My solution works, but I'm not sure if this is a correct usage of an initializer. Is there a more appropriate Rails convention for cleaning up those duplicate validation messages?

Comment: I think you can use ActiveModel::Validations, you can make a class for common validation and include that class on the model where you need to show common message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer the following approach, so I could also use the translations on other places within my app (like a hint message for instance):

```
class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: { message: I18n.t('common_errors.required_question' }
end
```

and

```
en:
  common_errors:
    required_question: "This is a required question"
```

Comment: van Rinj: If I will only have English-speaking users, would you still recommend using the EN config?  Either way, it seems that using the EN config or (an initializer) is the conventional approach.

Comment: personally I would, because most of the time users say they don't want multi-language but after some amount of time they always come back to that point, which is really a pain in the *** to find all strings and replacing it with localised strings. I think it's always a good approach to setup your string in your language file even if you only have 1 language to support :)

Comment: Good point about forward-thinking for what users may need in the future instead of what they want in the moment. No reason not to build a future-proof design.